# Saving file on SD card gets an error

Tags: arduino, intel-edison

I'm using Intel Edison with Arduino Breakout Board. I want to save file on SD card and I run a simple ReadWrite example on Arduino IDE. Everything works perfectly, I got an output:

> Initializing SD card...initialization done. Writing to
>   test.txt...done. test.txt: testing 1, 2, 3.

But then I plug the SD card into PC, the file does not exist or it's empty.

This is the example code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

File myFile;

void setup()
{
 // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
   while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }


  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
  // On the Ethernet Shield, CS is pin 4. It's set as an output by default.
  // Note that even if it's not used as the CS pin, the hardware SS pin 
  // (10 on most Arduino boards, 53 on the Mega) must be left as an output 
  // or the SD library functions will not work. 
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);

  if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");

  // open the file. note that only one file can be open at a time,
  // so you have to close this one before opening another.
  myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);

  // if the file opened okay, write to it:
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.print("Writing to test.txt...");
    myFile.println("testing 1, 2, 3.");
    // close the file:
    myFile.close();
    Serial.println("done.");
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }

  // re-open the file for reading:
  myFile = SD.open("test.txt");
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.println("test.txt:");

    // read from the file until there's nothing else in it:
    while (myFile.available()) {
        Serial.write(myFile.read());
    }
    // close the file:
    myFile.close();
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }
}

void loop()
{
    // nothing happens after setup
}
```

Comment: 1. Is there a *.flush()* method of the file object? If so, do call it before *.close()*. 2. If you comment out second opening (and of course related lines), does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this command to unmount

```
umount /media/sdcard
```

And it saved the problem.